# $f(z) =\prod_{n \in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}}\left(1+{z\over a+n}\right)e^{-z/(n+a)}$ is an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product

> If $a$ is not an integer, show that
> $$f(z) =\prod_{n \in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}}\left(1+{z\over a+n}\right)e^{-z/(n+a)}$$
> is an entire function.

Using the series expansion of $e^{-z/(n+a)}$, we get
\begin{align*}
\left(1+{z\over a+n}\right)e^{-z/(n+a)}& = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(1+{z\over a+n}\right){1\over k!}\left(-{z\over n+a}\right)^k\\
& = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(1+{z\over a+n}\right){1\over k!}(-1)^k{1\over (n+a)^k}z^k\\
& = \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k{1\over k!}\left({z^k\over(n+a)^k}+{z^{k+1}\over (a+n)^{k+1}}\right)\\
& = 1+\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k{k\over(k+1)!}{z^{k+1}\over (a+n)^{k+1}}.\\
\end{align*}
Similary computation shows that
\begin{align*}
\left(1+{z\over a+n}\right)e^{-z/n} = 1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k{(a+n)-kn\over k!(a+n)n^k}z^k.\\
\end{align*}
Now I'm trying to use the fact that if $a_n\neq -1$ for each $n$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges absolutely if and only if $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+|a_n|)$ converges. But I don't know how to show the convergence of infinite series in my case.

Comment: Maybe you should look at the Weierstrass Factorization Theorem.

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't think so. The exponential factor is not the canonical factor $E_k(z)$.

Comment: Think about the proof, not a canned formula.

Comment: $$f(z)=\frac{a\sin\pi(a+z)}{(a+z)\sin\pi a}e^{(1/a-\pi\cot\pi a)z}.$$

Comment: @TedShifrin I see. In my case, I can let the exponent to be $e^{-z/(n+a)}$ as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (R/|n+a|)^{2}<\infty$ for any fixed $R>0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you can make a more precise estimate:

$$
\left(1 + \frac{z}{a + n}\right)e^{-z/(n+a)} = \left(1 + \frac{z}{a + n}\right)\left(1 + -\frac{z}{a + n} + O(n^{-2})\right) = 1 + O(n^{-2})
$$

which converges; and in particular on every disc $|z| \leq R$, this convergence should be uniform; uniform convergence on compacts nets you holomorphicity.